# How to remove/disable last row/column of SRTM GeoTIFF in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, srtm

I've started using QGIS yesterday, and one of my main reasons to use it is to apply colormapped SRTM v4 over Google aerial imagery.

Everything is working fine, except that SRTM v4 elevation tiles have overlapping last row and last column (6001 x 6001 pixels), and that creates duplicated raster over the edges, which means an ugly, "unacceptable" border over the displayed image.

So before I consider editing the files to remove the last row and column, I wonder if there is a way to tell QGIS to ignore this part of the GeoTiff.

The image below (usind soft light blending mode) shows the problem over the latitude of -30°

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a virtual raster with both images.

You can do it in **Raster > Miscelaneous > Build Virtual Raster (Catalog)**.

It will be a quite small file that will allow you to open both images at the same time in QGIS, and set blending to them globally. That way the overlapping blending mode or transparencies won't show.

Two overlapping images with multiply blending mode:

[image: Two overlapping images with multiply blending mode]

Virtual Raster of the same images with multiply blending mode:

[image: Virtual Raster of the same images with multiply blending mode]